# Bonjour Host Discovery for REST Web Services

Tags: rest, bonjour, service-discovery, zeroconf

Up to now I have never worked with bonjour. I think it is an interesting approach for using it to discover hosts which run rest services (e.g. by defining a predefined URL for devices providing a specific service). 
I read that I can ping the host with Bonjour via the bonjour-name but I have not found an approach how to call a REST service with bounjour (where I usually also need the port). Is this possible or do you know some references? I am thinking on something like this: xservice.Alice.local/rest?abc=......

Thank you